# DataTable - Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable, datatables

I have datatable:

```
function drawRadnici() {

                $('#tableradnici').dataTable({ 

                    "ajax": {
               "url": 'track_radnici.php',
               "type": 'POST',
               "data": {ajdi:ajdi},
               },
                    paging: false,
                    //"dom":' <"search"f><"top"l>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">',
                    // end ,
                    "columns": [ {
                            "data": "datum"}, {
                            "data": "radnik"},{
                            "data": "radnih_sati"},{
                            "data": "cena"},{
                            "data": "ukupno"},{
                            "data": "ID"}
                    ],

                    "columnDefs": [

                            {
                        "targets": 5,
                        "data": "ID",
                        "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
                            // return data; 
                            return '<i value="'+data+'" class="fa fa-times"></i>';
                        }
                            }


    ]
                });

            };
```

and work fine, but when I have empty JSON data from database then I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

MY json when I havent data is:

```
{data:null}
```

WHat I was try to do - I try to add success function to ajax:

```
"ajax": {
               "url": 'track_radnici.php',
               "type": 'POST',
               "data": {ajdi:ajdi},
"success": function (data) {
if (data == null) {
$('#tabeleradnici').html('No result');
}
}
               },
```

so I try when I dont have data to add just text to #tabeleradnici ... but this also dont work ...

Comment: You could be use [fnDrawCallback](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnDrawCallback) for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if its null and make it empty so .length is still valid:

```
"success": function (data) {
    data = data || [];
}
```

---

Update:

```
function drawRadnici() {

    $('#tableradnici').dataTable({

        "ajax": {
            "url": 'track_radnici.php',
            "type": 'POST',
            "dataSrc": function (json) {
                if(!json.data){
            $('#tabeleradnici').html('No result');
            json.data = [];
        }
                return json.data;
            },     
            "data": {
                ajdi: ajdi
            }
        },
        paging: false,
        //"dom":' <"search"f><"top"l>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">',
        // end ,
        "columns": [{
            "data": "datum"
        }, {
            "data": "radnik"
        }, {
            "data": "radnih_sati"
        }, {
            "data": "cena"
        }, {
            "data": "ukupno"
        }, {
            "data": "ID"
        }],

        "columnDefs": [

            {
                "targets": 5,
                "data": "ID",
                "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
                    // return data; 
                    return '<i value="' + data + '" class="fa fa-times"></i>';
                }
            }


        ]
    });

};
```

Comment: dont work , so succes is just an idea, how I can solve this in other ways ?

Comment: I need to destoy #tabelaradnici if there is no data and just to show text 'NO data' ...

Comment: Can you add it into the render function? Or where your trying to get its length?

Comment: I post my full code with html, js ... so this is all ... what about render function ?

Comment: how I get : Uncaught ReferenceError: json is not defined

Comment: My bad I made a mistake in my code, change `return json.data` to `return data`

Comment: hm, ok, but how when I have data I get: No data available in table ... everytime table is empty ...

Comment: can you `console.log(data)` on the line before `if(!data){` and see what the result is? If its null then your never getting data back

Comment: and also #tabelaradnici dont get html text ... just say : No data available in table

Comment: Okay try my updated code, I have not used dataTables before but I think it returns an object with the data inside it so am doing `json.data`

Comment: I get: Object {data: Array[5]}data: Array[5]0: Object1: Object2: Object3: Object4: Objectlength: 5

Comment: Work, but this code dont work:  $('#tabeleradnici').html('No result'); so when I dont have data I dont get just text ...

Comment: Great, I'm not sure why the html() won't update, what kind of element is `#tabeleradnici`? it's possible that the dataTables library changes the table later on after this function is running. Again I have never used dataTables so can't really help you with that.

Comment: Then you can't set a tables html() with just text as its invalid markup, what will happen with your current code is `<table>some text</table>' try use $('#tabeleradnici').html('<tr><td>No result</td></tr>');

Comment: I was try but dont work, table wont to be destoyed, so I will hide parent div... I will try to see hat happend then

Comment: @dertdetg just happen to pass by. if you use datatable and try to add a custom message if the table is empty, you can use the oLanguage.sEmptyTable of the Datatable API. example : $('#example').dataTable( {
    "oLanguage": {
        "sEmptyTable":     "My Custom Message On Empty Table"
    }
} );